# UFTP is not working as expected

Tags: windows, udp, file-transfer, multicast, reliable-multicast

I am using UFTP to transfer files within the subnetwork computers.

But when I used -H to send only particular computers instead of sending to all computers, it is not working as expected.

Let me explain in detail :

1. I have two windows machines in same network of IP's 172.21.170.198,172.21.181.216 respectively.
2. From one of the system, I used below mentioned command to send the file

> uftp.exe   -R 100000    -H 172.21.170.198,172.21.181.216    e:\setup.exe

3. But both machines won't receive those file.

But if I use this command both machines will receive the file.

> uftp.exe    -R 100000    E:\setup.exe

I want to know whether I made any mistake.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks in Advance.
Kindly revert back for any clarifications.

Regards,
Thiyagu

Comment: Do the receivers print "Name not in host list" in their logs?  Also, do the receivers have an IPv6 addresses set up?

Comment: Also, in the case without `-H`, what does the server report as the ID of the client?

Comment: I can't understand clearly. Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: In the case where both machines receive, the sender will print "Received REGISTER from client 0xnnnnnnnn" for each registered receiver.  The number printed is the client's ID.  What are those values?  Also, if you run `ipconfig /all` from the command line of each receiver, what IP addresses (IPv4 and IPv6) are displayed for the first network interface listed?

Answer (score 2):

If ipv6 isn't enabled, it would look like this, converting the ipv4 addresses to hex (with a converter like http://www.kloth.net/services/iplocate.php):

```
uftp.exe   -R 100000    -H 0xAC15AAC6,0xAC15B5D8    e:\setup.exe
```

But if you have an ipv6 address on the client, the client id sort of comes from the end of it backwards.  Like if the address was "fe80::e5ca:e3ca:fea3:153f%5", the command would look like:

```
uftp.exe   -R 100000    -H 0x3f15a3fe    e:\setup.exe
```

(coming from "fe a3 15 3f")